# How to use host's docker in a container with the passed user?

Tags: docker

I'm binding the current user and a volume to a container using the following command.

```
docker run --user="$(id -u):$(id -g)" -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

When I try to call `docker ps` inside the container, I'm getting `/var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied` error. Because `/var/run/docker.sock` has `root` ownership in the host (therewithal in the container).

Is there any way to run the container as a `user` and access the host docker daemon inside the container using the same user?

Comment: In the command you write, you have a slash in the final `docker/sock` that should be a period `docker.sock`; is that just a copy/paste error?

Comment: What is the ownership and permissions of the Docker socket (probably the same inside and outside the container; try `ls -ln /var/run/docker.sock`); do they match the uid/gid you're passing in?  Do you need to [`docker run --group-add docker`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#additional-groups), perhaps?

Comment: Or, if you're giving the container unrestricted root access over the host anyways (you can `docker run` a new container running as root and bind-mounting any part of the host filesystem) you can run it `-u root` and it won't have permission problems.

Comment: Yes, it's just a copy&paste error.
The ownership and permissions of the Docker socket ``root`` inside and outside the container. 
It works well with root. I don't want to give root permission to the container.

Comment: I just want to run the docker container with user without any problem to access host's docker.

Comment: srwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jan  5 13:58 /var/run/docker.sock

Comment: With that ownership, the container process _must_ run as root to be able to access the host Docker (and potentially compromise the host).